# Using choice_value with EntityType::class doesn't select the right option when edit entity

Tags: symfony

I'm using Symfony3, I have Product entity and Tax entity.

```
 //Product
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Tax")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
 */
private $tax;
```

This is the ProductType

```
->add('tax', EntityType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Taxe',
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Tax',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'placeholder' => 'Tax',
            'multiple' => false,
            'expanded' => false,
            'required' => false,
            'choice_value' => function ($tax) {
                /** @var Tax $tax */
                return $tax->getRate();
            },
        ))
```

The problem is that when edit entity, the **placeholder** is selected not the right tax of this product  and when I remove **choice_value** the tax will be selected.

**Solved**:

To use choice_value , the value should be **unique**

Answer (score 0):

Strange, everything looks right hous.
The only thing I can suggest is try changing the way that 'class' is specified and also get rid of the comment in the 'choice_value' callable:

```
->add('tax', EntityType::class, array(
        'label' => 'Taxe',
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Tax',
        'choice_label' => 'name',
        'placeholder' => 'Tax',
        'multiple' => false,
        'expanded' => false,
        'required' => false,
        'choice_value' => function ($tax) {
             return $tax->getRate();
        },
))
```

Also, after making the change, make sure you clear your cache:

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

Try that, I can't think of anything else.

Comment: Is the value returned from `getRate()` unique at all? If not, maybe you need to make `$rate` in the Entity using Doctrine annotation unique, then you could use: `'choice_value' => rate` where `rate` is the property of the Tax Entity. That should work.